# I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm seeing this in logcat sometimes, but don't know what it means.

Answer (score 2):

I solved by passing view on in function argument

My XML

```
<TextView
android:onClick="@{ (view) -> handler.showSectionSelectionDialog(view) }"
```

My fragment

```
fun showSectionSelectionDialog(view: View) {
    Log.d(TAG, "showSectionSelection: clicked")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a binder message from onTransact(). if the process calling the service does not have the appropriate selinux permissions.
http://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_SEforAndroid_1#Android_Classes_and_Permissions.
you can simulate/get the same error from this snippet.

```
public void Run(){
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/cmd wifi");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
            Log.d(TAG, "Run: "+result.toString());
            tv.setText(result.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
```

returns the same logcat error.

(the cmd binary in adb sends a shellCommand binder transaction).
running `adb shell wifi` runs the command correctly though, since the shell selinux context has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: link to occurence in android open source project.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/heads/master/libs/binder/IPCThreadState.cpp#1250

Comment: What question are you asking here?